# Run node js with input from console in Sublime text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I want to running Javascript code with an input from console. I have followed this tutorial to run the program by node js (https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/) but I can't find how to put the input element in Sublime text.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add your input to the command: `"cmd": ["/usr/bin/nodejs", "$file", "This is my input"]`

2) get the input by: `process.argv[index]`

[Check my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5zEb.png)

Is this what you asking for?

**UPDATE:**

I dont find anyway to pass a variable during the build: 
Ref: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#variants

In your case, we still can edit `javaScript.sublime-build` to see the result interactively(not limit inputs number). Something like this: `"cmd": ["/usr/bin/nodejs", "$file", "This is my input", "2nd", "3nd", "put as many as you want"],`

Comment: Your method is add a new System Build. Is there any method that we put the input in console  and see the result interactively?( not limit inputs number)

Comment: Check my update, I dont know anyway to put input in console yet, but hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass input to the console. What you need is a REPL, for instance [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL). Once installed, you can launch “SublimeREPL: Node” from the command palette.